# Python-Gremlin driver in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

I'm trying to use the gremlinpython library to connect to Cosmos DB, and it seems like only the async queries are possible.

```
from gremlin_python.driver import client, serializer
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.driver import serializer

host = "my_host"
username = "my_username"
pwd = "COSMOS_KEY"

client = client.Client(
    host,
    "g",
    username=username,
    password=pwd)

# This works
callback = client.submit_async("g.V().hasLabel('question')")
callback.result().all().result()

# Does not work
g = traversal().with_remote(client)
g.V().hasLabel("question").to_list()
```

It is not clear what I'm missing as the only documentation provided by Microsoft is on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/quickstart-python showing only the first method.

Comment: For the second method, it should be `toList()` not `to_list()`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that Azure Cosmos DB supports Gremlin Bytecode. When you do something like :

```java
g = traversal().with_remote(client)
g.V().hasLabel("question").to_list()
```

you are using Gremlin Bytecode.

Please also see this quite old Git issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/439